# writing an 8 bit checksum in C

Tags: c, checksum

I am having trouble writing an algorithm for a 1byte / 8 bit checksum.
Obviously with 8bits over a decimal value of 255 the Most significant bits have to wrap around. I think I am doing it correctly.

Here is the code...

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int check_sum = 0;              //checksum
    int lcheck_sum = 0;             //left checksum bits
    int rcheck_sum = 0;             //right checksum bits
    short int mask = 0x00FF;            // 16 bit mask

    //Create the frame - sequence number (S) and checksum 1 byte

    int c;
    //calculate the checksum
    for (c = 0; c < length; c++)
    {
        check_sum = (int)buf[c] + check_sum;
        printf("\n Check Sum %d ", check_sum);      //debug
    }

    printf("\nfinal Check Sum %d", check_sum);      //debug

    //Take checksum and make it a 8 bit checksum

    if (check_sum > 255)            //if greater than 8 bits then encode bits
    {

        lcheck_sum = check_sum;
        lcheck_sum >> 8;    //shift 8 bits to the right

        rcheck_sum = check_sum & mask;
        check_sum = lcheck_sum + rcheck_sum;
    }


    //Take the complement
    check_sum = ~check_sum;


    //Truncate - to get rid of the 8 bits to the right and keep the 8 LSB's
    check_sum = check_sum & mask;

    printf("\nTruncated and complemented final Check Sum %d\n",check_sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [CRC8](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform/vboot_reference/+/master/firmware/lib/crc8.c)

Comment: What is your trouble? And what is the length here?

Comment: @samgak: This is a checksum, not a CRC.

Comment: what is c and length here....please post full code..

Comment: Length is just the number of characters in the message or number of bytes. C is just a counter

Comment: @mark: I only find `c`. where is an uppercase `C` actually?

Comment: @Olaf it's a lower case c. Autocorrect on my phone. Also thanks for the answer. The algorithm is from a textbook but when I did the checksum by hand I used your algorithm of wrapping the carry bit around and that worked. So I am just going to use that. The wrapping of the upper and lower using that particular mask was right from the textbook.

Comment: Textbooks often do not represent true life. Mine is from RL - never seen the folding, neither such code. If that code is exactly from that book, do yourself a favour and bin that book and get a better one;-) So, if my code worked, feel free to accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you are not doing it correctly, even *if* the algorithm would be as your code implies (which is unlikely).

**Standard warning:** Do not use `int` if your variable might wrap (*undefined behaviour*) or you want to right-shift potentially negative values (*implementation defined*). OTOH, for unsigned types, wrapping and shifting behaviour is well defined by the standard.

Further note: Use `stdint.h` types if you need a specific bit-size! The built-in standard types are *not* guaranteed (including `char`) to provide such.

Normally an 8 bit checksum of an 8 bit buffer is calculated as follows:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t chksum8(const unsigned char *buff, size_t len)
{
    unsigned int sum;       // nothing gained in using smaller types!
    for ( sum = 0 ; len != 0 ; len-- )
        sum += *(buff++);   // parenthesis not required!
    return (uint8_t)sum;
}
```

It is not clear what you are doing with all the typecasts or shifts; `uint8_t` as being guaranteed the smallest (unsigned) type, the upper bits are guaranteed to be "cut off".

Just compare this and your code and you should be able to see if your code will work.

Also note that there is not **the** single checksum algorithm. I did not invert the result in my code, nor did I fold upper and lower bytes as you did (the latter is pretty uncommon, as it does not add much more protection).

So, you have to verify the algorithm to use. If that really requires to fold the two bytes of a 16 bit result, change `sum` to uint16_t` and fold the bytes as follows:

```
uint16_t sum;
...
// replace return with:
while ( sum > 0xFFU )
    sum = (sum & 0xFFU) + ((sum >> 8) & 0xFFU);
return sum;
```

This cares about any overflow from adding the two bytes of sum (the loop could also be unrolled, as the overflow can only occur once).

Sometimes, CRC algorithms are called "checksum", but these are actually a very different beast (mathematically, they are the remainder of a binary polynomial division) and require much more processing (either at run-time, or to generate a lookup-table). OTOH, CRCs provide a **much** better detection of data corruption - but **not to manipulation**.

Comment: False. Integer overflow is *undefined,* whereas signed right-shift of negative values is merely *implementation-defined* and does the right thing on all but the most obscure platforms.